# Getting MSBUILD working with an ASP.Net website in Jenkins

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, jenkins, msbuild, .net-3.5

**Introduction**

My asp.net website with C# builds (& publishes) perfectly on my development machine.

The solution uses .net framework 3.5

I use Visual Studio 2008

The website contains a bin folder with the AjaxControlTollkit dll

**The issue**

I am attempting to set up Jenkins for continuous integration

Jenkins is running on a windows server 2008 r2 based machine

I am referencing the SVN repository and all the code appears to get checked out correctly.

*The build fails with the following error:-*

> Build started 10/09/2014 13:20:02.
>
> Project "D:\DEV\Manzen_fx_35\Manzen.sln" on node 0 (default targets). 
>   Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU". Manzen_fx_35:
>   Copying file from "D:\DEV\Manzen_fx_35\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" to
>   "..\Manzen_fx_35\Bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll".   Copying file from
>   "D:\DEV\Manzen_fx_35\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.pdb" to
>   "..\Manzen_fx_35\Bin\AjaxControlToolkit.pdb". ASPNETCOMPILER : error
>   ASPRUNTIME: The precompilation target directory
>   (D:\DEV\Manzen_fx_35\PrecompiledWeb\SourceCode) cannot be in the same
>   tree as the source application directory (D:\DEV\Manzen_fx_35). Done
>   Building Project "D:\DEV\Manzen_fx_35\Manzen.sln" (default targets) --
>   FAILED.
>
> "D:\DEV\Manzen_fx_35\Manzen.sln" (default target) (1) -> (Manzen_fx_35
>   target) ->    ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: The precompilation
>   target directory (D:\DEV\Manzen_fx_35\PrecompiledWeb\SourceCode)
>   cannot be in the same tree as the source application directory
>   (D:\DEV\Manzen_fx_35).
>
> ```
> 0 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)
> ```

I obviously don't have to do anything in Visual Studio to get the site to build successfully. 
MSBUILD is however struggling with the reference to the `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` & `AjaxControlToolkit.pdb` files and specifically to the precompilation target directory.

I've not found any other answers that seem specific enough to help.
I imagine the solution is fairly simple and is probably staring me in the face but having never used MSBUILD in isolation before (I do everything in VS) I'm a bit lost.

Here's hoping someone can help.

Comment: Can you provide detailed\diagnostics msbuild log from your visual studio and from your Jenkins environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the source of the problem.

As I wrote in the original post, I suspected that the answer was indeed staring me in the face and it was.

The statement `"ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: The precompilation target directory (D:\DEV\Manzen_fx_35\PrecompiledWeb\SourceCode) cannot be in the same tree as the source application directory (D:\DEV\Manzen_fx_35)"` identified that the precompilation target directory cannot be in the same tree as the source application directory.

I changed the precompilation target directory and the MSBUILD in Jenkins now works. Both an F5 Build and a Website Publish are unaffected.

The precompilation target directory setting is obviously not an issue when building via an F5 or the website is published in Visual Studio BUT it is if you are using MSBUILD standalone.

Comment: If you feel you have got an answer, you should [mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer so that others can know that it has been answered. It helps.

Comment: your question was here for 4 days. i answered it yesterday and *you* just figured it out? cool. another kick in the nutz for answering a fkng question.

Comment: wazz - I have other things to do rather than just wait for an answer on here. If you hadn't noticed we've just had a weekend too and I certainly don't work then unless I have to.

Answer (score 0):

i would start by removing the toolkit and see what happens. but i don't think it's the problem.

i think it has more to do with, "The **precompilation target directory** ... cannot be in the same tree as the source application directory." looks like there is some precompilation going on and compiled files are being sent to the wrong dir; or the build should be grabbing files from the already-precompiled directory, not the source; or some variation.

look for the precompilation "routine". it would have the term, 'aspnet_compiler' in it.